# Canvas animation with 'lineargradient' darker on one side and doesn't resize properly?

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas

1). This animation has a a weird effect where it colors part of the screen darker than it should be (it should be more transparent not opaque), also

2). It resizes the screen in the wrong way where it gets smaller than it should be.

Here's the code:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('c');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var shiftingValue = 0.1;
var wavePos = 0;

function flowGrad() {

   //Clearing between frames
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width);

  //Creating linear gradient
    var lineargradient = context.createLinearGradient(canvas.width/2, 0, canvas.width/2, canvas.height);
    lineargradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(255,0,0,.2)');
    lineargradient.addColorStop(wavePos, 'rgba(0,255,0,.5)');
    lineargradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0,0,255,.2)');

    context.fillStyle = lineargradient;


    //Drawing triangle
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0, 0);
    context.lineTo(canvas.width, 0);
    context.lineTo(canvas.width/2, canvas.height);
    context.fill();

    shiftingValue += 0.01;
    //Uses absolute value of sin to generate an oscilating value.
    wavePos = Math.abs(Math.sin(shiftingValue));
    requestAnimationFrame(flowGrad);
}

function init() {
    // Register an event listener to call the resizeCanvas() function 
    // each time the window is resized.
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
    // Draw canvas for the first time.
    requestAnimationFrame(flowGrad);
}

function resizeCanvas() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}

init();
```

and [codepen](https://codepen.io/Yonkai/pen/JMaoaq?editors=0010) link. Help much appreciated. I'm using chrome if want the effect isn't happening for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1). This animation has a a weird effect where it colors part of the screen darker than it should be (it should be more transparent not opaque)

You have swapped height and width; change this line:

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width);
```

to

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

> 2). It resizes the screen in the wrong way where it gets smaller than it should be.

The animation loop is invoked several times asynchronously within the resize handler. Add a reference for the animation frame request in global scope, then cancel the request every time you resize:

```
var ref;

// ...
function init() {
  window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
  cancelAnimationFrame(ref);  // cancel current, if any
  ref = requestAnimationFrame(flowGrad);
}
```

As well as in the loop itself:

```
function flowGrad() {
  // ...
  ref = requestAnimationFrame(flowGrad);
}
```

On top of that you could always add CSS rules to avoid the canvas being offset and therefor produce scroll bars:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
```

Also remember to set the canvas size the first time inside `init()` by calling `resizeCanvas()` manually.